# Two parts of my python list changed when only one should

Tags: python, list

I just started working on a simple genetic algorithm with a bunch of dots which each have a series of instructions to move. The instructions are a list of integers which I compare to a dictionary: `movekey = {1:(1,1),2:(1,0),3:(1,-1),4:(0,-1),5:(-1,-1),6:(-1,0),7:(-1,1),8:(0,1)}` (where each of the tuples are the change in `x` and `y` values). Each individual is a list of lists, one has its current position and the other is its movement list ex: `[[0, 0], [4, 4, 8, 1, 7]]`. A list of a bunch of these individuals is then created to form a population (`pop` in code).
The function to create an initial population is this:

```
def createinitpop(size):
    pop = []
    for i in range(size): pop.append([origin,[random.randint(1,8) for i in range(5)]])
    #the variable origin is preset to be [0,0]
    return pop
```

then, to move all of the individuals one step, i use this function:

```
def movedots(pop):
    for i in pop:
        print('i:',i)
        i[0][0]+= movekey[i[1][step]][0]
        # the 'step' referenced here begins at zero and counts up, i've only run it on step 0
        i[0][1] += movekey[i[1][step]][1]
        print('i:', i)
    return pop
```

The problem is that when I run this second function, each iteration changes all the individuals in the population. (However Ii have found that when I hardcode an example population into the `movedots` function it works just fine). Here is the result of running both of those functions with two individuals (both returned populations are printed)

```
[[[0, 0], [6, 5, 2, 1, 8]], [[0, 0], [4, 7, 2, 1, 1]]]
i: [[0, 0], [6, 5, 2, 1, 8]]
i: [[-1, 0], [6, 5, 2, 1, 8]]
i: [[-1, 0], [4, 7, 2, 1, 1]]
i: [[-1, -1], [4, 7, 2, 1, 1]]
[[[-1, -1], [6, 5, 2, 1, 8]], [[-1, -1], [4, 7, 2, 1, 1]]]
```

Ideally the location of the individuals in that final line should be different because their first movement is different, but as you can see the third `i` is the same as the second `i`, suggesting that it is using the same value.

I don't know if I just don't understand how lists work or if I'm missing something stupid.

Comment: You're reusing the same `origin` list over and over.

Comment: the createinitpop function only runs once at the beginning to create the population in which all individuals start at the origin, the problem i have is more with the second function. If there was something else that you think is a problem with reusing origin could you please expand.

Comment: No, your problem is in `createinitpop`. The second function is just where the problem becomes visible.

Comment: Im still not understanding, shouldn't the second function be adding different numbers to the [0,0] in each individual, therefore they will end up with different locations. Is there a specific change that you think I could add to fix this?   edit: just figured it out, thank you

Comment: `origin` is a "reference" or "pointer" (if you wish) to a data structure holding two integers: 0 and another 0. In your loop `append([origin, ...])` simply copies the reference to _the same object_ instead of creating a new one. Therefore, it should not surprise you that by changing this object in one place of the code this change _becomes visible_ in other places (since `origin` is still pointing to the same object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pointed two references to the same place:

```
for i in range(size): pop.append([origin,[random.randint(1,8) for i in range(5)]])
```

You now have *three* references to the *same* list.  When you change it from any of the three channels, you change the data for each of them.  Try an implicit copy operation:

```
for i in range(size): pop.append([origin[:], ...
```

This will give you a shallow (one-level) copy of `origin` for each of your nested references.

Comment: ohhhh. I see, thank you so much